# how to remove <?php tag in command line and view laravel

Tags: php, laravel, syntax, command, laravel-blade

"php tag" auto insert in line when i run command that have "php" like php artisan, php artisan key:generate, php artisan make:controller,...

[image: Image 1]

when i view-source in my web browser i see "php tag" auto add in first line

[image: image-2]

How can i remove that tag, my other laravel projects aren't being like this.
This project in other computers not being like this.
I try to remove and pull new code but doesnt work, other computers not being like this except me!
I also try to reinstall php but doesn't work!

Comment: Add a space after the `<?php` and before the `<!doctype html>`

Comment: So if you just remove it then what?

Comment: What are you using to generate the files?

Comment: I can't find it right now, but the last time I saw this question on SO, someone had accidentally added a "<?php" string in a bootstrapped file. Worth deleteing/regenerating the application cache, and if that doesn't work, start looking through autochecked files such as e.g. all console commands.

Comment: no, i pull code from git, other computer doesn't beeing like this except me

Comment: as @JoelHinz mentioned try `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: @AmrAly not working return "<?phpCache clear successfully."

Comment: that's weird try to restart your machine .

Comment: restart 3 times :sad

Comment: check the `public/index.php` file

Comment: Do you have any `auto_prepend_file` setting in your php.ini ?

Comment: You have the text "<?php" being echoed out somewhere. You will need to find it. We cannot do that for you as we don't have access to your code. Maybe it is index.php, maybe it is artisan.php, maybe it is in a service provider somewhere. Unfortunately, you will either need to hunt it down yourself, or make the code public.

Comment: @Mike What is the full name of your view-source file with extention

Comment: Did you fix this issue? I'm experiencing this kind of issue. Thanks